# Is there any way for translating to another language month and day names in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, package, translation, translate

I need to know is there any package or framework or built in support available for this.

Answer (score 0):

I use moment in my projects. I really like it.

And it's easy to use.

Install moment package:

```
npm install moment --save
```

After installation, you can:

```
moment.locale('pt')
moment().format('LLLL'); // Sexta-feira, 25 de setembro de 2020 12:24

moment.locale('en')
moment().format('LLLL') // Friday, September 25, 2020 12:25 PM
```

You can check their website: https://momentjs.com/